# how to setup Azure AD Client Credentials Flow with Mediawiki

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-installation

I am trying to setup a Mediawiki on Azure. And need to have OAuth support with Client Credentials Flow so a client application can request access token from Azure AD, and then client uses the requested access token to call Mediawiki API to access wiki resources.

I am wondering what are the steps I can follow in order to have such setup.

Currently I am thinking use Azure Web App to create Mediawiki and turn on Express Auth mode in AAD for this app. Not sure if I still need to configure anything in Mediawiki for validating the access token or any extension needed.

I also saw some tutorials create VM instead of Azure Web App. But I can not find any Client Credentials tutorials for Mediawiki.

[**Update section below**]

I would like to clearify my question a bit more in case I didn't.
I would like to configure Azure AD (which is an Identity platform) to enable client credential. So my client app can get access token from Azure AD and then client app can use this token to query data directly to Medaiwki API.

Example:

Step 1:
Client send post request to Azure AD endpoint using client crendentials

```
POST:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxx_an_AAD_tenantID_xxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/token
 
Headers:
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
 
Body:
{
    client_id=<New App Registration Client ID>,
    client_secret=<New App Registration Client Secret>,
    grant_type=client_credentials
}
 
Response:
{    
    "token_type": "Bearer",    
    "expires_in": "xxx",    
    "ext_expires_in": "xxx",    
    "expires_on": "xxx",    
    "not_before": "xxxx,    
    "resource": "xxx",    
    "access_token": <Access_Token>
}
```

Step 2: using the Access token from step 1 to query Medaiwiki API data

```
GET:
https://myMediawiki.com/api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo&siprop=namespaces&format=json
 
Headers:
Authorization: Bearer <Access_Token>
```

I am wondering **how to configure such Mediawiki**. In order to take the access token at Mediawiki.

I understand there are some OAuth extensions. But those extensions seem to act as a whole authorization server. In my case, I would like AAD act as Authorization Server and AAD will create authorized Client App with client_id and Client_secret in step 1.

Some references:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow
- https://dasith.me/2018/12/31/client-credentials-flow-with-azuread/

Comment: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:OAuth2_Client might be what you are looking for.

Comment: thx @Tgr, but I do not see any documentation/configuration example to support Client Credential Flow, which is to grant application access to mediawiki api. Client App get access token from Azure AD and application uses it to access Medaiwiki api.

Comment: So you want MediaWiki to be the OAuth server and Azure the OAuth client? In that case, check out https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:OAuth

Comment: Hi @Tgr, I would say not exactly to your question above. I would like to configure Azure AD (which is an identity platform) to get access token for client app. Then use the access token to directly call Mediawiki API for data access. (please see my Update section in my origin question) thanks

Comment: So how would you assign the client IDs to MediaWiki users?

Comment: Hi @Tgr, I actually don't need to care about MediaWiki users (individual users) at the moment. Because my goal is to create a client/registered app in Azure AD. this App will have access token from AAD and access data from Mediawiki. So to me, I feel (could be wrong) Mediawiki need to configure something as Resource Server to validate the token with AAD (but I am not sure what exact setup I need)

Comment: Okay but how do you determine what MediaWiki permissions the app should have? Or are we jut talking about anonymous access to a private MediaWiki instance?